# Wildfly stopped logging

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I am using Wildfly standalone. I used to check the logs in the standalone/log folder where there used to be a folder for every past day and a server.log folder for the current day.

Some days ago, Wildfly just stopped logging. The information in server.log has not changed since days and no new files for days are created. However, Wildfly works fine. I have been checking the configuration files but I have not been able to find any variable or anything that may inhibit the log. The ouptput of `/subsystem=logging:read-resource(recursive=true)` is :

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=logging:read-resource(recursive=true)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "add-logging-api-dependencies" => true,
        "use-deployment-logging-config" => true,
        "async-handler" => undefined,
        "console-handler" => {"CONSOLE" => {
            "autoflush" => true,
            "enabled" => true,
            "encoding" => undefined,
            "filter" => undefined,
            "filter-spec" => undefined,
            "formatter" => "%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n",
            "level" => "INFO",
            "name" => "CONSOLE",
            "named-formatter" => "COLOR-PATTERN",
            "target" => "System.out"
        }},
        "custom-formatter" => undefined,
        "custom-handler" => undefined,
        "file-handler" => undefined,
        "log-file" => undefined,
        "logger" => {
            "com.arjuna" => {
                "category" => "com.arjuna",
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "handlers" => undefined,
                "level" => "WARN",
                "use-parent-handlers" => true
            },
            "org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler" => {
                "category" => "org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler",
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "handlers" => undefined,
                "level" => "WARN",
                "use-parent-handlers" => true
            },
            "org.jboss.as.config" => {
                "category" => "org.jboss.as.config",
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "handlers" => undefined,
                "level" => "DEBUG",
                "use-parent-handlers" => true
            },
            "sun.rmi" => {
                "category" => "sun.rmi",
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "handlers" => undefined,
                "level" => "WARN",
                "use-parent-handlers" => true
            },
            "jacorb" => {
                "category" => "jacorb",
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "handlers" => undefined,
                "level" => "WARN",
                "use-parent-handlers" => true
            },
            "jacorb.config" => {
                "category" => "jacorb.config",
                "filter" => undefined,
                "filter-spec" => undefined,
                "handlers" => undefined,
                "level" => "ERROR",
                "use-parent-handlers" => true
            }
        },
        "logging-profile" => undefined,
        "pattern-formatter" => {
            "PATTERN" => {
                "color-map" => undefined,
                "pattern" => "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"
            },
            "COLOR-PATTERN" => {
                "color-map" => undefined,
                "pattern" => "%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"
            }
        },
        "periodic-rotating-file-handler" => {"FILE" => {
            "append" => true,
            "autoflush" => true,
            "enabled" => true,
            "encoding" => undefined,
            "file" => {
                "relative-to" => "jboss.server.log.dir",
                "path" => "server.log"
            },
            "filter" => undefined,
            "filter-spec" => undefined,
            "formatter" => "%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n",
            "level" => "ALL",
            "name" => "FILE",
            "named-formatter" => "PATTERN",
            "suffix" => ".yyyy-MM-dd"
        }},
        "root-logger" => {"ROOT" => {
            "filter" => undefined,
            "filter-spec" => undefined,
            "handlers" => [
                "CONSOLE",
                "FILE"
            ],
            "level" => "INFO"
        }},
        "size-rotating-file-handler" => undefined,
        "syslog-handler" => undefined
    }
}
```

How could I fix this? Why this may have happened when no changes in the configuration were made?

Comment: Can you add the output from the following CLI command? `/subsystem=logging:read-resource(recursive=true)`

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Done!

Comment: The configuration looks correct. I'm not sure why it would just stop logging. Did it maybe happen after you redeployed an application? I'm just wondering if the deployment maybe has a logging configuration file in it.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I don't think it is related to the deployment. I have deployed the same application in two Wildfly installlations in different servers and at the begining both were logging correctly. Then, one of them stopped logging while the other is still working fine. I have gone through some of the configuration files in both of them and I have found no differences between them. I am not sure if there are more files I should go through...

Comment: If you don't have a logging configuration file in your deployment, then logging should be configured by the logging subsystem which looks correct.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue with Wildfly 10.1.0.Final. After days of working correctly, it suddenly stopped logging. As a workaround we open the logging configuration and re-save it (without changing anything), the server then will start logging again.